# Use function on many elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that will validate the file size of an attachment and add errors if the file size exceeds the limit set, but it is limited to a specific file field with an id at the moment and i would like to be able to use the function on many file fields.

If a user wants to add say two images then they can click a button to clone the file field.

```
// First Example with ID
$('#animal_image_file_0').bind('change', is_valid_dog_image_size);

function is_valid_dog_image_size() {
  $this = $('#animal_image_file_0');
    if($this[0].files[0].size < 3000000){ // valid
     if ($this.closest(".form-group").hasClass("has-error")) 
      $this.closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      $this.siblings(".help-inline, .form-inline .has-feedback .form-control-feedback, .has-feedback").css("display", "none");
    return true
  } else { // error
    if (!$this.closest(".form-group").hasClass("has-error")) 
      $this.closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
      $this.siblings(".help-inline, .form-inline .has-feedback .form-control-feedback, .has-feedback ").css("display", "block");
    return false;
   }
  }
```

So I thought to apply this to many file fields I could use a class instead and then fire the function using the .on('click') method when the button to clone a field is clicked, but the assignment of $(this) in the function will not work now will it?

```
$('.add_nested_fields').on('click', function(){
  $('.animal_file').bind('change', is_valid_dog_image_size);
});

function is_valid_dog_image_size() {
  $this = $('.animal_file');
    if($this[0].files[0].size < 3000000){ // valid
     if ($this.closest(".form-group").hasClass("has-error")) 
      $this.closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      $this.siblings(".help-inline, .form-inline .has-feedback .form-control-feedback, .has-feedback").css("display", "none");
    return true
  } else { // error
    if (!$this.closest(".form-group").hasClass("has-error")) 
      $this.closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
      $this.siblings(".help-inline, .form-inline .has-feedback .form-control-feedback, .has-feedback ").css("display", "block");
    return false;
   }
  }
```

When i click .add_nested_fields it clones the file field so how could i go about ensuring that i could use the same function on all instances of this class in the DOM?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you will be attaching multiple handlers to each field:

```
$('.animal_file').bind
```

is problematic, because you want to handle only events on the new field (the other handlers stay). The best way for your situation is to use a delegate handler (JQuery version [1.4.2+](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and [1.7](http://api.jquery.com/on/)). The idea is that you attach the event handler on the parent element and filter for the target:

```
$('#parent-of-animal_file').on('change', '.animal-file', is_valid_dog_image_size);
```

Then, in your handler, simply use the native `this` and wrap it in a jQuery object:

```
function is_valid_dog_image_size() {
  $this = $(this);
  ...
```

Comment: ok that makes more sense.. so when you say parent element, could i use the class of the form itself or does it have to be the div above the .animal_file ?

Comment: @Richlewis it can actually be any element up the DOM. It can even be `body` for that matter, but you must make sure that it doesn't target fields that it should not.

Comment: thank you, ive been trying to get my head around delegation and i think you just helped me understand it a little bit more

Comment: and just to clarify something else, is '.animal-file' being assigned to $(this) ?

Comment: @Richlewis suggest you read: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/. There isn't all too much to it. You'll master it fairly quickly, and you need it often.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `$this` to a jQuery wrapper of `this`. jQuery sets it properly for you when running an event callback.

```
$('.add_nested_fields').on('click', function(){
  $('.animal_file').bind('change', is_valid_dog_image_size);
});

function is_valid_dog_image_size() {
    $this = $(this);
    if(this.files[0].size < 3000000){ // valid
     if ($this.closest(".form-group").hasClass("has-error")) 
      $this.closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      $this.siblings(".help-inline, .form-inline .has-feedback .form-control-feedback, .has-feedback").css("display", "none");
    return true
  } else { // error
    if (!$this.closest(".form-group").hasClass("has-error")) 
      $this.closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
      $this.siblings(".help-inline, .form-inline .has-feedback .form-control-feedback, .has-feedback ").css("display", "block");
    return false;
   }
  }
```

Comment: could you provide an example please, as im getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment ' in the console

Comment: ahh i see, not quite sure that works though as now getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

Comment: Edited. I made a mistake last time.